# How do you pass a property as a parameter

Tags: vb.net, properties, parameters

I have a class, Player, which has 6 or so properties, all integers. For my project, there needs to be some sorting, and i'd like to be able to write a function that accepts a list of players and a property to sort them by returns a list of the players sorted by the passed property:

```
Class Player
   Public Property PID
   Public Property RunsScored
   PublicProperty  BallsFaced
End Class

Class AnotherClass
    Public Shared PlayerList As New List(Of Player)

    Public Player sort(list As List(Of Player), prop As Property)
        'sort the list by prop
        Return sorted list
    End Function
```

But I have no idea if this is a thing, does it have a name? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is to take a delegate which returns a property for each object in the collection

```
Public Player sort(list As List(Of Player), func As Func(Of Player, Object))
  'sort the list by prop
  Return sorted list
End Function
```

Then you can use a lambda at the call site to specify the property you want to use

```
sort(list, Function(player) player.PID)
```

Comment: It sounds good, but I don't really get what you mean, is there like a name name for doing all this so I can research it?

Comment: @user1091236 if you want to research it look for the term "lambda expressions".  here is a nice site to look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253.aspx

Comment: Thanks, i'll have a look. I have only ever seen lambda as the sign of a wave's wavelength!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Reflection in the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy.aspx) to complete the task.

At first the sort function (an example how to get value is included, sorting is your business).

```
Public Sub SortPlayer(list As List(Of Player), prop As Reflection.PropertyInfo)
    ...
    Dim value = prop.GetValue(list(1), Nothing)
    ...
End Sub
```

Now how to call it:

```
Public Sub CallSort()
    Dim MyList As New Generic.List(Of Player)
    ...
    SortPlayer(MyList, GetType(Player).GetProperty("RunsScored"))
End Sub
```

The problem is that name property by string can cause a problem at runtime. So a function is necessary.

```
Public Sub CallSort2()
    Dim MyList As New Generic.List(Of Player)
    SortPlayer(MyList, GetType(Player).GetProperty(GetPropertyName(Function() MyList(0).PID)))
End Sub
```

`GetPropertyName` implementation can be found e.g. in [NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Name)](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/780cf8ef-4340-4e27-b240-7beef43c03a2/notifyofpropertychange-name)

**Note**

[JaredPar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18345974/669527) solution is probably better but this is an answer to the question.

I recommend you to pay attention to [List(Of T).Sort Method (Comparison(Of T))](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Ah I looked at that method, but this is for a college project and you need to show you can actually perform a sort for yourself.